# Transparent Plane Still Casts Shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

In cycles render I have a RGBA movie of a man waving that I'm using as a texture on a plane.  Using nodes, I can make the alpha channel transparent, but the plane is still casting its rectangular shadow on the plane behind it.  I want only the man's shadow on the back plane. Is there a way to do that?
[image: Example picture]

Comment: Did you accidentally disable Transparent Shadows for the scene or material? It should work with those enabled.

Comment: No, transparent shadows are enabled on both planes.

Comment: @papabrewsky I'm having a hard time recreating your problem: I always get the right transparency and shadows no matter what. Do you mind posting your blend file? Create a still of your video file and pack it along for testing.

Comment: What movie format are you using - most don't support alpha. Are you sure the alpha is 100% clean? not at 98% alpha.

Comment: This might be a bug.  I started over & WAS able to replicate this problem.  I then changed the Image Input node to 'generated' which caused the plane to go magenta. Then I re-selected the movie (yes RGBA) from the hard drive (not internal) & everything started working...only the man was casting a shadow.  So I went back to this file & tried the very same thing, but it did not fix it. So ????  BTW, since the new file worked correctly, I used that one.